# How to split a list of fields separated both by ',' and by '||'?

Tags: bash

I have a scenario where I would get the output in the below format:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6||7,8,9,10,11,12||13,14,15,16,17,18||19,20,21,22,23,24
```

I am able to store the entire results into a bash variable.

For example I have created a bash variable `myvar` and some 6 other variables called `a,b,c,d,e,f`. `myvar` contains the above resultset.

What I need is when I loop through myvar in the first loop it should assign as following:

```
a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4,e=5,f=6
```

and prepare a html body and send it across
and in second loop

```
g=7,h=8,i=9,j=10,k=11,l=12
```

again prepare a html body and send it across

I am struck in the loop section

And then do some html email body, which I am able to do when it returns only

> 1,2,3,4,5,6

Let me know if provided information is relevant enough for you guys answer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split a line of input by setting `IFS='|'`, but unfortunately you use `||` as a separator. [This answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7904/can-ifs-internal-field-separator-function-as-a-single-seperator-for-multiple-c) shows the trick of performing a second array parameter expansion using and `IFS=''`. In your case this amounts to:

```
#!/bin/bash

# '(' execute the following commands in a subshell, see `man bash` (search for
# "Compound Commands").
(

# disable filename expansion
set -f

input="1,2,3,4,5,6||7,8,9,10,11,12||13,14,15,16,17,18||19,20,21,22,23,24"

# split by '|'
IFS='|'
lines=(${input})

# remove empty elements
IFS=""
lines=(${lines[@]})

for ((i=0; i < ${#lines[@]}; i++)); do
  echo "Processing ${i}: '${lines[${i}]}'"

  IFS=','
  elements=(${lines[${i}]})

  for ((j=0; j < ${#elements[@]}; j++)); do
    echo "  found element ${elements[${j}]}"
  done

  # here you can either use ${elements[${0}]}, ..., ${elements[${5}]} directly
  # or you can assign them to your variables:
  # set a="${elements[${0}]
  # set b="${elements[${1}]
  # ...

done

)
```

**Output**

```
% ./foo.sh
Processing 0: '1,2,3,4,5,6'
  found element 1
  found element 2
  found element 3
  found element 4
  found element 5
  found element 6
Processing 1: '7,8,9,10,11,12'
  found element 7
  found element 8
  found element 9
  found element 10
  found element 11
  found element 12
Processing 2: '13,14,15,16,17,18'
  found element 13
  found element 14
  found element 15
  found element 16
  found element 17
  found element 18
Processing 3: '19,20,21,22,23,24'
  found element 19
  found element 20
  found element 21
  found element 22
  found element 23
  found element 24
```

**References**

- [bash(1) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. Its comes out as expected. However, could you please extend your answer on how do I assign to different variables for each value passing in the loop into this statement.

Comment: Thank you "Micha Wiedenmann", It comes out perfectly as expected. Could you please also extend your answer on how to assign it to different variables in each loop. I think the last part of the my question was incorrect. In each loop the values of variables a,b,c,d,e,f should change dynamically. For example in first loop it will be 1,2,3,4,5,6 and in second loop this should change to 7,8,9,10,11,12. Please bare with my question, as I am just two days old into this bash scripting. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @JagapathiRaju I updated the code to show how you could set the variabels, but I would suggest you use the elements array instead.

Comment: ,Thanks I was able use in this fashion and I am able to use these variables values assigned as part of each of the loop to send emails downstream. a=${elements[0]}
b=${elements[1]}.Thank you for your help.

Comment: @JagapathiRaju please remember to vote and accept answers.

Comment: I beleive I have marked your reposne as answer. Not sure on how to vote as I just joined today to this group.

Answer (score 0):

This is just example which you can extend

below you can use $1, $2, $3, $4 etc for your further processing (like assigning to variable a, b c..) or use $ variables directly etc.

```
x="1,2,3,4,5,6||7,8,9,10,11,12||13,14,15,16,17,18||19,20,21,22,23,24"
echo $x | cut -d'|' -f1- --output-delimiter=$'\n' | sed -e '/^[ ]*$/d' > /tmp/data.txt
for line in `cat /tmp/data.txt`; do awk -F',' '{print $1, $2, $3, $4, $5}' <<< $line; done
```

please note there is (needs to be ) "back quote character" around `cat /tmp/data.txt`